# CorDapp flows and REST APIs

Tags: corda

I am working on a system that needs to initiate and track Corda flows. The system has its UI implemented as a single-page web application, and its backend based on serverless architecture (AWS Lambda or Azure Cloud Functions). This effectively rules out the use of Observables or Websockets, as the backend code (a serverless function) is not going to be running long enough to receive an update via RPC connection. I need a different way to track flows in a way that can provide more or less timely feedback to the user looking at the webapp.

The way I am looking to achieve this is to use the standard REST pattern for long-running transactions. In short, the flow will be kicked off by a POST request, and will return `202 Accepted code` with `Location` header pointing to a flow resource URL. The flow will be identified by its `StateMachineRunId` encoded in the URL, so the UI code could make a GET request every so often to see where the request is. There is no requirement to provide real-time updates, so polling seems to be a viable strategy. The challenge is to reliably construct a sensible response to the polling request.

Whilst the flow is running it's not a problem, I can just call `stateMachinesSnapshot` and get the details of the running flow based on its UUID. The question is what to do with the completed flows. For flows that have run its course and produced one or several transactions, it's possible to obtain the mapping from the flow UUID to the transaction hash via `stateMachineRecordedTransactionMappingSnapshot`. The problem is that this mapping becomes bigger and bigger with every recorded transaction, and on a high-throughput system it would slow everything down -- I have not performance-tested it though, just a hunch.

One further problem with the transaction mapping is that if a flow failed to produce any persistent transaction, either by design, or by error, the UUID will no longer resolve to anything and the UI code will get `404 Not Found` error. I guess this may be interpreted contextually and appropriate feedback provided, but this seems cumbersome.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to durably and scalably associate a unique identifier of a flow instance with either its current status or its results and termination condition. I wonder if there is something in the RPC or Corda API itself that could make it easier?

Comment: When I was writing this article about Braid (https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-braid-server-and-openapi-generator-for-corda-flows-api-s-d24179ccb27c), I was in contact with one of the developers (Farzad Pezeshkpour (a.k.a Fuzz)) and he mentioned that they are working on "Receive notifications from flows’ progress trackers and vaults’ TrackBy queries". Maybe it's worth contacting him (he's on Corda Slack) and ask him about the approach they're taking to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Our latest release of CordaOS has a new function that grants the ability to suspend a flow during long-running operations to improve throughput

More information @https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/api-flows.html#calling-external-systems-inside-of-flows

Comment: That's really cool feature, thanks for the heads up. However, I'm not sure I see how this is related to the question?